# What does "to the prejudice of discipline" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I am reading a book and I came across a phrase I don't understand:

> A newspaper office seems to attract every conceivable sort of person, **to the prejudice of discipline**.

I don't know what to make of *"to the prejudice of discipline"*.  Can someone please explain?

Please search the [text of the book](http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/etext05/8king10h.htm) for the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case:

- **prejudice** means "detriment; damage".

> prejudice:
>
> - [..]
> - damage or injury; detriment: *a law that operated to the prejudice of the majority*.
> - **to the prejudice of**: to the detriment of.
>
> *([source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prejudice))*

- **discipline** means "behavior in accord with rules of conduct".
- **"to the prejudice of discipline"** means that the discipline suffers because the newspaper office attracts all kinds of people. 
  The next sentence from the book shows an example of this:

> Zenana-mission ladies arrive, and beg that the Editor will instantly abandon all his duties [..]

Comment: I believe it has an Army origin, *conduct prejudicial to the maintenance of discipline* being (at the time) a useful charge to bring when nothing else fitted. Even if not, it has a military echo that was certainly intended.

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks for the extra information, it sounds like it's quite appropriate for this Kipling book.